# Change color of contents in Mat Expansion on hover and focus

Tags: css, angular, material-design

I am writing css to change the color of the text and arrow indicator on focus and hover. However the indicator arrow acts separately. I want it to change when you hover over the whole panel. Currently the arrow indicator only changes when you hover directly over it Basically when the whole panel has the focus or hover change the title and indicator to my css: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-imycgv?file=styles.css

```
.mat-expansion-indicator:hover::after,
.mat-expansion-indicator:focus::after{
  color: yellow;
}

.mat-expansion-panel:hover,
.mat-expansion-panel:focus{
  background-color: red;
}
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description:hover, .mat-expansion-panel-header-title:hover,
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description:focus, .mat-expansion-panel-header-title:focus{
  color: orange;
}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below option 
mat-expansion-indicator is not direct child of panel, so onhover of panel, change color of indicator

```
.mat-expansion-panel:hover  .mat-expansion-indicator::after,
.mat-expansion-panel:focus  .mat-expansion-indicator::after{
  color: yellow;
}
```

codesandbox for reference - https://codesandbox.io/s/angular-hh3oz

Comment: I tried to save it in stackblitz, for some reason it is not allowing me to save, copied everything to codesandbox, Hope it works :)